# Changing Int Values to a String

Tags: java, int, tostring

I am trying to preform a simple math operation with a few numbers. Once completed I want the numbers, of type int, to be changed to a String. I am able to get the code to compile for the first 4 else if statements, but the 5th one is giving me a problem when I create n5x. Am I not allowed to create a value in a else statement? If so is there a way around this? Thank you.

```
                           if (n1==1){
                                int n1x = ((n1*10 +n2) + (n3*10+n4)+(n5));
                                n1s = Integer.toString(n1x);

                                outFile.println(n1s);}
                            else if (n2==2){
                                int n2x = (n2 + (n1*10 + n3)+(n4*10+ n5));
                                n2s = Integer.toString(n2x);
                                outFile.println(n2s);}
                            else if (n3==3){
                                int n3x = ((n3*10 +n2) + n1+ (n4*10+n5));
                                n3s = Integer.toString(n3x);
                                outFile.println(n3s);}
                            else if (n4 == 4){
                                int n4x =  (n4 + (n3 +n2*10)+(n5+n1*10));
                                n4s = Integer.toString(n4x);
                                outFile.println(n4s);}
                            else 
                                int n5x  = ((n5) + (n4+ n3*10) +  (n2+n1*10));
                                n5s = Integer.toString(n5x);
                                outFile.println(n5s);
```

Comment: Use proper indentation/bracing style and you'll avoid many bugs.

Comment: ...and if not for avoiding bugs; format the code for us that'll attempt to answer your question.

Comment: This is why the end brace gets its own line

Answer (score 7):

Your else clause lacks braces.

The variable n5x is defined only inside the else clause. Without the braces, the else clause consists only of the declaration.

It should look like this:

```
 else {
    int n5x  = ((n5) + (n4+ n3*10) +  (n2+n1*10));
    n5s = Integer.toString(n5x);
    outFile.println(n5s);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing  { } on the last else statement

Answer (score 0):

else should be in braces. it should be as follows -

```
                       else {
                            int n5x  = ((n5) + (n4+ n3*10) +  (n2+n1*10));
                            n5s = Integer.toString(n5x);
                            outFile.println(n5s);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last `else` clause:

```
else 
  int n5x  = ((n5) + (n4+ n3*10) +  (n2+n1*10));
  n5s = Integer.toString(n5x);
  outFile.println(n5s);
```

Is actually interpreted this way by the Java compiler:

```
else {
     int n5x  = ((n5) + (n4+ n3*10) +  (n2+n1*10));
}
n5s = Integer.toString(n5x);
outFile.println(n5s);
```

On a general note, you should have `{}` in any control statement that have more then one statement.